# how to convert string array into 2 dimensional string array in android

Tags: android, android-intent, multidimensional-array

```
my activity needs to send a 2 dimensional array to next activity

i am succesfully fetching my data in next activity but it is to be in 2 dimensional format due to some reason 
so how can i convert this data into 2 dimensional format in next activity

in brief i am getting my data but not able to arrange it in 2 dimensional format
curDts = new String[][] {
                {"26","8"},
                {"27"},
                {},
                {"13"},
                {},
                {},
                {},
                {"15","18"},
                {},
                {"2"},
                {},
                {}
        };
in first activity i am doing this to send data
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String lineSeperator = System.getProperty("line.separator");

        for(String[] row:curDts)
            sb.append(Arrays.toString(row)).append(",");

        String text = sb.toString();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("key",text);
        sendBroadcast(intent);

2nd activity

Bundle b = arg1.getExtras();
    String[] curdts = b.getStringArray("key");
        Log.v("chking the intent",""+curdts);
```

Comment: I think this data is complex enough to qualify being put in DB.

Comment: How does it look the content of String text; ? What does Arrays.toString(row) output for the first row?